# 4 ERRORS GENERATED WHILE INSTALLING BITCOIND

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, secp256k1

I need your help plz.
I have been struggling for weeks to make bitcoind work in my mac terminal.
I installed all required programs and dependencies: xcode, bitcoin core, openssl, homebrew, and cloned the bitcoin repo but still when I run the "sudo make install" command, fours errors are generated and the bitcoin-cli commands are not there.
Below is the output of the 4 errors that showed up in my terminal,

make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_common_a-key.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Could you copy paste the full error message ?

Comment: Try to download and install it again in a new directory https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/